# how can set the ControlBrushKey in a dictionary for the all dataGrids?

Tags: wpf, datagrid, resourcedictionary

I have this dictionary:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type StackPanel}">
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="12,12,20,20"/>
    </Style>

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGrid}">
        <Setter Property="IsReadOnly" Value="true"/>
        <Setter Property="CanUserAddRows" Value="false"/>
        <Setter Property="CanUserDeleteRows" Value="true"/>
        <Setter Property="AutoGenerateColumns" Value="false"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Visible"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Visible"/>
    </Style>


    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black"/>
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
        <Style.Resources>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}" Color="SkyBlue" />
        </Style.Resources>
    </Style>
```

In my views, I load the dictionary and the dataGrid get the propertd of the DataGrid, but they don't use the properies of the DataGridRow.

I would like to know how can I set the properties of the DataGridRows, because I would like to change the color of the selected rows when the dataGrid has not the focus because the defaulr grey colours is not seen good.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `DataGridRow` `IsSelected` property in a style trigger as shown below. You can then modify the colour of the selected rows when they are selected.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="SkyBlue"/>
    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
    <Style.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}" Color="SkyBlue" />
    </Style.Resources>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="SkyBlue"/>
            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Tomato" />
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```